# (IDEA Java + TomCat + Servlet API + Maven) + подключение библиотеки = ошибка 500 – Internal Server Error и ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, servlet

Цель - программа с web интерфейсом на java, которая получает из облака данные и результат выводит в браузер.  Управление программой должно осуществляться в браузере.

Действую по теме - https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/305-sozdanie-prosteyshego-web-proekta-v-intellij-idea-enterprise-edition-poshagovo-s-kartinkami
Использую - java + TomCat + Servlet (собрал все в IDEA). Для подключения библиотеки, которая отсутствует в официальном репозитории, я создал в корне проекта папку lib и положил туда biblioteka.jar. В pom.xml добавил:

```
<dependency>
             <artifactId>biblioteka</artifactId>
             <groupId>com.biblioteka</groupId>
             <scope>system</scope>
             <version>1.1</version>
             <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/biblioteka.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

В итоге на html странице жму кнопку, которая запускает методы библиотеки, что приводит к прекращению построчного выполнения программы в компиляторе и ошибке в браузере -

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/biblioteka/bib1
```

папка out\artifacts\mysuperproject_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes пуста. Если я скопирую классы в эту папку, то ошибка исчезает. Как правильно подключить библиотеку, чтобы джавамашина увидела классы библиотеки?

Comment: Неплохо было бы приложить стектрейс ошибки из логов и код

Comment: Нашел ошибку ClassNotFoundException, но не могу исправить @Sergi